# Looking for a way to connect a ribbon cable to a breadboard

Tags: connector, cables, prototyping

I am currently looking to buy a 16-pin TE Micro-MaTch male cable and convert it to something I can plug into my breadboard (similar to a .1" pitch connector)

Someone mentioned using a breakout board, but the one I did end up finding seems to be discontinued. Are there any alternatives to something like this? https://www.midi-hardware.com/?section=prod_info&product=FatBreak

the 16-pin male connector --> standard black female connector is exactly what I'm looking for, but not exactly sure how to go about going from the male <--> male to male <--> standard black female connector.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Terminating a ribbon cable to a breadboard is challenging because the ribbon cable has a pitch of 0.05" and the breadboard 0.1". The solution involves terminating it to holes on either side of the central trough in the breadboard, so that half of the connections are on the left, half on the right of it.

I assume that you are not obliged to use the micro-match connector. I assume that you can install a different connector on the ribbon cable. If so, this is how I would do it:

1. Get a [DIP plug](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NNK&n=dip_ribbon_cable_plugs) with a [0.3" row spacing](https://www.digikey.ee/short/7d829vfh).
2. Mass terminate it to the ribbon cable
3. Plug the DIP plug to the breadboard so it straddles the central trough.

[image: DIP plug in breadboard]

{Original Content}